# Sturm liouville Boundary Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

> Find the complete set of eigenvalues $\lambda$ and their corresponding eigenfunctions of the singular Sturm-Liouville  Boundary Value Problem.
>
> $[(1-x^2)u'(x)]' + \lambda u(x) = 0$   on the interval of $ 0<x<1$
>
> $u(0) = 0$
>
> $u(1) < \infty$
>
> $u'(1) < \infty$

I have tried numerous Sturm Liouville Boundary Value problems, but never done problems involving boundary conditions where there are inequalities and infinities, I have tried so far the following:

$$[(1-x^2)u'(x)]' + \lambda u(x) = 0$$

$p(x) = (1-x^2)$, $\space$     $q(x) = 0$ , $\space$ $r(x) = x$;

If $\lambda = 0$

we have $[(1-x^2)u'(x)]' = 0$;

Integrate both sides respect to x which yields,

$(1-x^2)u'(x) = C_1$

$u'(x) = \frac{C_1}{(1-x^2)}$

$u(x) = C_1 ln(1-x^2) + C_2$

The condition that implies $u(0) = 0$ implies $C_1 = 0$, $C_2 = 0$ Hnece $\lambda = 0$ is not an eigenvalue.

From here I am not sure how to proceed to solve the question itself where inequalities are involved with infinites. Any help to this question will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a boundary problem for Legendre polynomials (pl. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials)
Therefore the eigenvalues have the form of $\lambda=n(n+1)$ where $n$ is arbitrary nonegative integer n.

Comment: As a matter of fact, only the Legendre polynomials of *odd* degree vanish at $x=0$. Therefore, $n$ must be a positive odd integer.